# How to create a Desktop Application which starts after user logged in?

Tags: java, vb.net

How to create a windows application , which should start right after user logged in? I want to give user to fill his name and details before he can access the desktop.
**Without filling the form user shouldn't be able to access the desktop(the PC)** also the user shouldn't be able to access the task manager to kill this application without filling the form . Anyone can give me a sample code or example , thanks a lot

Comment: This probably isn't the right site for this question.  It doesn't seem to be about programming, and definitely not about Java or VB.NET.  But it sounds like you're describing logging in.  You want your users to have to log in twice?

Comment: Try looking up "kiosk mode"

Comment: Yes it is like a another log in screen

Answer (score 1):

Simply just add new window
-make a form by add textbox for password and uname
-make a table for id and pass into database
-connect database with this form
-and make this form as a starting form

Comment: yes, but the main thing is , the user shouldn't be able to close it or kill it without filling it .